# Testing the scope of application of a logistic regression model

Tags: machine-learning, logistic, predictive-models, application, domain-adaptation

My aim is to assess whether I can apply a logistic regression that was fitted on a sample A (where I have explanatory variables and the outcomes) to a different sample B where I don't know the outcomes yet.

The measure later when I have outcomes would be discriminatory power.

What statistical approaches can I use here? Is this a problem that is known and studied in statistics? Can we apply methods in the context of dataset shift here?

Can we argue with some sort of similarity between A and B? If we assume that the joint distribution of $(X,y)$ or better the conditional distribution of the features $y$ given the target $X$ is the same on A and B?

Comment: How can you hope to "test" the model in any meaningful way when you don't yet have the outcomes?  Could you clarify what you're hoping to achieve?

Comment: @whuber I am aware that I need strong assumptions. If e.g. I assume that the joint distribution of (X,y) is the same on A and B then testing something like X on A being similar to X on B could help. I see that this is not the perfect situation but isn't it possible in practice that I have to assess whether I can use a model before I see outcomes?

Comment: I still don't get it: you state you don't have any relevant data.  No amount of assumptions will enable you to test the model!

Comment: @whuber right, mabye I should edit the question. I would like to assess whether an application of the model to data B can be justified. I would test the model later when I have the lables. Then the targer would be high discriminatory power. ..

Comment: @whuber I see that you miss rigor in my statement. It is also true that in finance models (often logistic regression) are applied to data that is rather different to what they were developed on ... I wonder whether one can say something meaningful in this applied setting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is **no way** to compare joint distributions of $(X, y)$ between A and B sets, when you haven't seen any single observation of $y$ on the B set. Thus, you cannot directly measure whether the datasets are similar enough. You have to **rely on bare intuition**.  However, you can do some indirect checks to aid your intuition:

#### Obtain proxies for $y$

You can invent a metric $\tilde{y}$ which is expected to correlate with $y$, and see how the predictive power of the model $p(\tilde{y}|X)$ changes between A and B sets.

For example, in credit scoring you can get information about defaults on other loans in bureau, or use credit card utilization and early delinquency rates as a proxy to default rate.

#### Compare distributions of $X$

Having no data, you could make a heroic assumption that $p(y|X)$ is simimlar on A and B. However, even in this case your model could be useles on B, if the unconditional distribution of $X$ on B is very different. You can check this by comparing distribution of individual components of $X$ on A and B. If you want some numerical metrics of difference of two distributions, you can use KL divergence, or "population stability index".

#### Assess individual coefficients

Sometimes adequacy and/or generalizing ability of linear models (including GLM such as logistic regression) can be judged from individual coefficients. If every coefficient conforms your expectations of how the corresponding regressor should affect your target, you can hope that the model generalizes well.

However, as it was said in the comments, **no amount of assumptions will enable you to test the model** unless you have your $y$s. Thus, I would advise to  concentrate your attention on the ways to measure $y$ in the quickest and cheapest way.

Comment: thank your for your answer. Do you have any reference where such an analysis is done?

Comment: I have done such analysis while woirking in retail credit scoring. Parts of it are described in the book "Credit risk scorecards" by Naeem Siddiqi - look for "population stability" and "reject inference".

Comment: Do you think any multivariate analysis would help? A PCA approach?

Comment: What do you want to achieve with it?

Comment: to give more information: it is a credit scoring/rating system. It it developed on a set of credit and it should give reasonable discriminatory power on another set. Obviously we will only see in the comming months which customers were bad ones

Comment: how about looking at variable residuals in B and comparing to the variable residuals in A? It could give a rough estimate of any variation in B that is not captured in A and therefore provide early warning of big issues. It will not alert to subtle issues, but at least will flag up major ones before unblinding set B.

Comment: @Richard, are you thinking of PCA of the X variables in the two data sets then perhaps clustering or discriminant analysis to determine if there is significant differences in the two datasets?

Comment: @ReneBt right, looking at residulas could be interesting.I have to think about what to do in the case of logistic regression. About PCA: I am not 100% sure but at least this would give some insight. Do you have any references for your ideas?

Comment: @DavidDale The book you recommend. Would you recommend someone to buy it? What about the his other book "intelligent credit scoring"? are there lists of must read books in credit scoring? Thank you!

Comment: At least I would recommend to look at its digital version. Haven't read the other book. Never seen good lists of must read books on this topic.

Comment: @Richard, I'm afraid I've not got references, I commented rather than answered as that is how I would try out but I've never done it. I would therefore be in your position and need to do some literature searching then failing that do some experimentation.

Comment: @ReneBt just stumbles upon Box's (1949) M-test for homogeneity of covariance matrices obtained from multivariate normal data ... this is one thing I will consider